# Error while copying object from S3 Golang "NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist"

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I want to copy a file from one folder to another on the same S3 bucket. while doing this I am getting an error `NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist` my code is given below.

```
sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String("ap-south-1")})
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
Oldpath := "folder1/folder2/a+b.pdf"
newBaseFolder  := "folder3"
svc := s3.New(sess)
bucketName := "mybucket.test"
source := bucketName + "/" + oldPath                                 // Oldpath = "folder1/folder2/a+b.pdf"
                                                                     //newBaseFolder = "folder3"
newPath := newBaseFolder + "/" + strings.SplitN(oldPath, "/", 2)[1] //newPath = "folder3/folder2/a+b.pdf" 
_, err = svc.CopyObject(&s3.CopyObjectInput{
            Bucket:     aws.String(bucketName), // bucketName = "mybucket.test" 
            CopySource: aws.String(url.PathEscape(source)),
            Key:        aws.String(newPath)})
if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```

**Error message**

```
{
"err": "NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist."
"status code": 404
}
```

Comment: What are the values of your variables?

Comment: It is written as comments on the right side

Comment: In your example the variable `bucket` seem not be defined.

Comment: Are you sure the file exists? ... can you try with the CLI instead: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

Comment: Double check that `mybucket.test/folder1/folder2/a.pdf` definitely exists. If yes, I would start by logging (or at least printing) your bucket and path variables immediately before you use them. Your comments are helpful to understand what's *supposed* to be going on, but they don't guarantee that is in fact what's happening. If there are no obvious issues, try the same operation manually with the CLI :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `url.QueryEscape` instead of  `url.PathEscape` as `url.QueryEscape` can encode special characters such as `+` which cannot be encoded by `url.PathEscape` (this technique worked for me).

```
...
_, err := svc.CopyObject(
            &s3.CopyObjectInput{
                Bucket:     aws.String("document.as.a.service.test"),
                CopySource: aws.String(url.QueryEscape(source)),
                Key: aws.String(newPath),
            },
        )
...
```

And sometimes if `copySource` is not properly encoded error can be displayed as `NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist`

Just in case to avoid confusion Go-AWS-SDK `copyObject` functions `copySource` will be *the path of an existing file*, and `Key` *is the newPath or destination that you want your file to be copied*.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason is that `url.PathEscape` replaces slashes in path with `%2F`